# The best Linux Open-source wiki with native support for Windows (NTLM) authentication

Tags: software-rec, active-directory, markdown, wiki, restructuredtext

I need to set up a wiki for our engineering group; we are part of an Enterprise-wide Windows Active Directory domain.  Most of the corporate IT applications use NTLM to authenticate (automatically via Internet Exploder); while I'm not part of corporate IT, I recognize that Single Sign-On (SSO) is important for user acceptance.

I am hoping to find a free and open-source wiki that is well-tested and can be hosted on linux<sup>See End Note 1</sup>, while allowing corporate windows laptops to automatically authenticate without a password prompt.

I have seen some hacks to make [moin](http://moinmo.in/) authenticate with NTLM<sup>See End Note 2</sup>, but I don't know how well this would actually work in practice; so any deployment experiences with moin + NTLM would be valuable.  I have also seen [FOS Wiki](http://foswiki.org/), but [FOS Wiki doesn't seem to have support for automatic login](http://foswiki.org/Support/Question690).

### Question:

In short, I am looking for the best free, open-source, linux wiki implementation with native, automatic NTLM authentication support<sup>See End Note 3</sup>; I give bonus points if it can use [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) or [reStructured Text](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html).

---

End Notes:

1. If I felt like running this under Windows, I could use [Screwturn wiki](http://www.screwturn.eu/); however, the thought of hosting web services on windows makes me feel all dirty inside.
2. See [this post on wikimatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/forum/t51-ntlm-support-windows-authentication)
3. If such a thing even exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound up using `moin`, which I installed in `/opt/moin`... I host it under `apache2` using WSGI... I could not make `moin` perform automatic NTLM authentication unless I hosted it under Windows...  I hosted it under linux, but it still authenticates against our local LDAP server in the NT domain.

This is `/opt/moin/config/wikiconfig.py`... if you use it, understand that I sanitized the config and "foo" in the LDAP authentication code below is really the name of my company... everybody has a different LDAP setup, so you may need to tweak some of the authentication parameters in your environment... YMMV...

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
# IMPORTANT! This encoding (charset) setting MUST be correct! If you live in a
# western country and you don't know that you use utf-8, you probably want to
# use iso-8859-1 (or some other iso charset). If you use utf-8 (a Unicode
# encoding) you MUST use: coding: utf-8
# That setting must match the encoding your editor uses when you modify the
# settings below. If it does not, special non-ASCII chars will be wrong.

"""
    MoinMoin - Configuration for a single wiki

    If you run a single wiki only, you can omit the farmconfig.py config
    file and just use wikiconfig.py - it will be used for every request
    we get in that case.

    Note that there are more config options than you'll find in
    the version of this file that is installed by default; see
    the module MoinMoin.config.multiconfig for a full list of names and their
    default values.

    Also, the URL http://moinmo.in/HelpOnConfiguration has
    a list of config options.

    ** Please do not use this file for a wiki farm. Use the sample file
    from the wikifarm directory instead! **
"""

import os

from MoinMoin.config import multiconfig, url_prefix_static
from MoinMoin.auth.ldap_login import LDAPAuth
from MoinMoin.auth import MoinAuth


class Config(multiconfig.DefaultConfig):

    # Critical setup  ---------------------------------------------------

    # Directory containing THIS wikiconfig:
    wikiconfig_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

    # We assume that this config file is located in the instance directory, like:
    # instance_dir/
    #              wikiconfig.py
    #              data/
    #              underlay/
    # If that's not true, feel free to just set instance_dir to the real path
    # where data/ and underlay/ is located:
    #instance_dir = '/where/ever/your/instance/is'
    instance_dir = '/opt/moin'

    # Where your own wiki pages are (make regular backups of this directory):
    data_dir = os.path.join(instance_dir, 'data', '') # path with trailing /

    # Where system and help pages are (you may exclude this from backup):
    data_underlay_dir = os.path.join(instance_dir, 'underlay', '') # path with trailing /

    # The URL prefix we use to access the static stuff (img, css, js).
    # Note: moin runs a static file server at url_prefix_static path (relative
    # to the script url).
    # If you run your wiki script at the root of your site (/), just do NOT
    # use this setting and it will automatically work.
    # If you run your wiki script at /mywiki, you need to use this:
    #url_prefix_static = '/mywiki' + url_prefix_static


    # Wiki identity ----------------------------------------------------

    # Site name, used by default for wiki name-logo [Unicode]
    sitename = u'QA Wiki'

    # Wiki logo. You can use an image, text or both. [Unicode]
    # For no logo or text, use '' - the default is to show the sitename.
    # See also url_prefix setting below!
    logo_string = u'<img src="%s/common/moinmoin.png" alt="MoinMoin Logo">' % url_prefix_static

    # name of entry page / front page [Unicode], choose one of those:

    # a) if most wiki content is in a single language
    page_front_page = u"DefaultPage"

    # b) if wiki content is maintained in many languages
    #page_front_page = u"FrontPage"

    # The interwiki name used in interwiki links
    interwikiname = u'QAWiki'
    # Show the interwiki name (and link it to page_front_page) in the Theme,
    # nice for farm setups or when your logo does not show the wiki's name.
    #show_interwiki = 1


    # Security ----------------------------------------------------------

    # This is checked by some rather critical and potentially harmful actions,
    # like despam or PackageInstaller action:
    #superuser = [u"YourName", ]
    superuser = [u"Mike_Pennington", ]

    # IMPORTANT: grant yourself admin rights! replace YourName with
    # your user name. See HelpOnAccessControlLists for more help.
    # All acl_rights_xxx options must use unicode [Unicode]
    acl_rights_before = u"Mike_Pennington:read,write,delete,revert,admin"
    acl_rights_default = u"Mike_Pennington:read,write,delete,revert,admin, Known:read,write All:read"

    # The default (ENABLED) password_checker will keep users from choosing too
    # short or too easy passwords. If you don't like this and your site has
    # rather low security requirements, feel free to DISABLE the checker by:
    #password_checker = None # None means "don't do any password strength checks"
    password_checker = None

    # Link spam protection for public wikis (Uncomment to enable)
    # Needs a reliable internet connection.
    #from MoinMoin.security.antispam import SecurityPolicy


    # Mail --------------------------------------------------------------

    # Configure to enable subscribing to pages (disabled by default)
    # or sending forgotten passwords.

    # SMTP server, e.g. "mail.provider.com" (None to disable mail)
    #mail_smarthost = ""

    # The return address, e.g u"Jürgen Wiki <noreply@mywiki.org>" [Unicode]
    #mail_from = u""

    # "user pwd" if you need to use SMTP AUTH
    #mail_login = ""


    # User interface ----------------------------------------------------

    # Add your wikis important pages at the end. It is not recommended to
    # remove the default links.  Leave room for user links - don't use
    # more than 6 short items.
    # You MUST use Unicode strings here, but you need not use localized
    # page names for system and help pages, those will be used automatically
    # according to the user selected language. [Unicode]
    navi_bar = [
        # If you want to show your page_front_page here:
        #u'%(page_front_page)s',
        u'DefaultPage',
        u'SiteIndex',
        u'RecentChanges',
        u'FindPage',
        u'HelpContents',
    ]

    # The default theme anonymous or new users get
    theme_default = 'modernized'


    # Language options --------------------------------------------------

    # See http://moinmo.in/ConfigMarket for configuration in
    # YOUR language that other people contributed.

    # The main wiki language, set the direction of the wiki pages
    language_default = 'en'

    # the following regexes should match the complete name when used in free text
    # the group 'all' shall match all, while the group 'key' shall match the key only
    # e.g. CategoryFoo -> group 'all' ==  CategoryFoo, group 'key' == Foo
    # moin's code will add ^ / $ at beginning / end when needed
    # You must use Unicode strings here [Unicode]
    page_category_regex = ur'(?P<all>Category(?P<key>(?!Template)\S+))'
    page_dict_regex = ur'(?P<all>(?P<key>\S+)Dict)'
    page_group_regex = ur'(?P<all>(?P<key>\S+)Group)'
    page_template_regex = ur'(?P<all>(?P<key>\S+)Template)'

    # Content options ---------------------------------------------------

    # Show users hostnames in RecentChanges
    show_hosts = 1

    # Enable graphical charts, requires gdchart.
    #chart_options = {'width': 600, 'height': 300}


    # LDAP authentication ---------------------------------------------------

    ldap_authenticator1 = LDAPAuth(
        server_uri='ldap://10.16.16.237/',
        bind_dn = r'Americas\%(username)s',
        base_dn='dc=amer,dc=foo,dc=com',
        bind_pw='%(password)s',
        scope=2,
        referrals=0, # LDAP REFERRALS (0 needed for AD)
        search_filter='(sAMAccountName=%(username)s)',
        givenname_attribute='givenName',
        surname_attribute='sn',
        aliasname_attribute='displayname',
        email_attribute='mail',
        email_callback=None, # callback function called to make up email address
        coding='utf-8', # coding used for ldap queries and result values
        timeout=10, # how long we wait for the ldap server [s]
        start_tls=0, # usage of Transport Layer Security 0 = No, 1 = Try, 2 = Required
        tls_cacertdir=None,
        tls_cacertfile=None,
        tls_certfile=None,
        tls_keyfile=None,
        tls_require_cert=0, # 0 == ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER (needed for self-signed certs)
        bind_once=True, # set to True to only do one bind - useful if configured to bind as the user on the first attempt
        autocreate=True, # set to True to automatically create/update user profiles
        #name='ldap', # use e.g. 'ldap_pdc' and 'ldap_bdc' (or 'ldap1' and 'ldap2') if you auth against 2 ldap servers
        report_invalid_credentials=True, # whether to emit "invalid username or password" msg at login time or not
    )

    auth = [ldap_authenticator1,] # this is a list, you may have multiple ldap authenticators
                                   # as well as other authenticators

    cookie_lifetime = (0, 4) # no anon user sessions, 1h session lifetime for logged-in users

    # customize user preferences (optional, see MoinMoin/config/multiconfig for internal defaults)
    # you maybe want to use user_checkbox_remove, user_checkbox_defaults, user_form_defaults,
    # user_form_disable, user_form_remove.
    ('checkbox_defaults',
    {
    'mailto_author': 0,
    'edit_on_doubleclick': 1,
    'remember_last_visit': 0,
    'show_comments': 0,
    'show_nonexist_qm': False,
    'show_page_trail': 1,
    'show_toolbar': 1,
    'show_topbottom': 0,
    'show_fancy_diff': 1,
    'wikiname_add_spaces': 0,
    'remember_me': 1,
    },
    "Defaults for user preferences, see HelpOnConfiguration/UserPreferences.")
```

I am using wsgi with moin, so I needed `/opt/moin/moin.wsgi`

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
"""
    MoinMoin - mod_wsgi driver script

    To use this, add those statements to your Apache's VirtualHost definition:

    # you will invoke your moin wiki at the root url, like http://servername/FrontPage:
    WSGIScriptAlias / /some/path/moin.wsgi

    # create some wsgi daemons - use someuser.somegroup same as your data_dir:
    WSGIDaemonProcess daemonname user=someuser group=somegroup processes=5 threads=10 maximum-requests=1000 umask=0007

    # use the daemons we defined above to process requests!
    WSGIProcessGroup daemonname

    @copyright: 2008 by MoinMoin:ThomasWaldmann
    @license: GNU GPL, see COPYING for details.
"""

import sys, os

# a) Configuration of Python's code search path
#    If you already have set up the PYTHONPATH environment variable for the
#    stuff you see below, you don't need to do a1) and a2).

# a1) Path of the directory where the MoinMoin code package is located.
#     Needed if you installed with --prefix=PREFIX or you didn't use setup.py.
#sys.path.insert(0, 'PREFIX/lib/python2.3/site-packages')

# a2) Path of the directory where wikiconfig.py / farmconfig.py is located.
#     See wiki/config/... for some sample config files.
#sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/wikiconfigdir')
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/moin')
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/moin/code')
sys.path.insert(0, '/opt/moin/config')

# b) Configuration of moin's logging
#    If you have set up MOINLOGGINGCONF environment variable, you don't need this!
#    You also don't need this if you are happy with the builtin defaults.
#    See wiki/config/logging/... for some sample config files.
#from MoinMoin import log
#log.load_config('/path/to/logging_configuration_file')

from code.MoinMoin.web.serving import make_application

# Creating the WSGI application
# use shared=True to have moin serve the builtin static docs
# use shared=False to not have moin serve static docs
# use shared='/my/path/to/htdocs' to serve static docs from that path
application = make_application(shared=True)
```

FWIW, this is my apache config file... `/etc/apache2/conf.d/moin.conf`

```
# Create some wsgi daemons - use these parameters for a simple setup
WSGIDaemonProcess moin user=www-data group=www-data processes=5 threads=10 maximum-requests=1000 umask=0007

#
WSGIProcessGroup moin
```

This is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/netwiki`...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName netwiki.us.foo.com

  RewriteEngine   on
  RewriteCond     %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://netwiki.us.foo.com/$1 [L,R]

  DocumentRoot /opt/moin/code/
  WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/moin/moin.wsgi
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName netwiki.us.foo.com
  DocumentRoot /opt/moin/code/
  WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/moin/moin.wsgi

  # Generate with...
  # openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out netwiki.pem -keyout netwiki.key
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/netwiki.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/netwiki.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am in the same situation, and I run MediaWiki. NTLM authentication is handled in Apache by means of the [PyAuthenNTLM2](https://github.com/Legrandin/PyAuthenNTLM2) module on mod-python; MediaWiki logs in a user (and automatically creates a wiki account for them the first time) by means of the [AutomaticaREMOTE_USER](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aAutomaticREMOTE_USER) extension.

My experience is pretty good: SSO works fine, users don't notice at all that the wiki does not belong to the Windows domain, and IT folks are happy that passwords are kept secure.

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of PyAuthenNTLM2, which I wrote because the previous Apache plugin I was using (Apache2::AuthenNTLM2) is unmaintained and does not work with Windows 7 default (and reasonable) security policy (NTLMv2).

Comment: Thanks for the information, Mediawiki would be an option if it weren't so heavily dependent on PHP... however, I might be able to find a way to leverage PyAuthenNTLM2 with moin...

Comment: After authentication has taken place, the username is passed by Apache to the webservice/CGI in the REMOTE_USER variable. If MoinMoin can use REMOTE_USER you are done.

Answer (score 1):

We use [MindTouch Core](http://www.mindtouch.com/products/platform) (open source edition). Runs along on a Linux VM under Mono, uses AD for auth. Been using it company-wide since 2009.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check  http://www.jasig.org/cas

It provides enterprise single sign-on service.